# cakephp change default action for controller (i.e. from "index")

Tags: cakephp, controller, action

I have some controllers I want to default to table and not index, as they present better in a different format than my index pages use.  How can I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. For others:

The file `/app/config/routes.php` contains the routing configuration, and default action can be changed there.  E.g.,

```
Router::connect(
   '/pages',
   array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')
);
```

This will send a request to app/pages/ to the "display" action, not the usual "index."

More here:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration#!/view/46/Routes-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
The file /app/config/routes.php file change the defult controller name 


Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

to

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Your defult controller', 'action' => 'your defult conroller method'));
```